# Was Blaster in Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome supposed to be the big farmhand in the original Mad Max movie?

Tags: mad-max

In the movie "Mad Max", there was a large farmhand character. In the "Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome" movie, Max fights a masked giant in the dome. I have always imagined it was the same character (big farmboy) from "Mad Max" that had managed to survive the apocolypse by way of his brawn (as "Blaster"). When Max unmasks him, Blaster smiles a "No hard feelings" smile at Max. Is Blaster in "Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome" supposed to be the same character as the farmhand in "Mad Max"?

Comment: Here is a link referencing this question, but not exactly answering it: madmaxmovies.com/flubs/othertrivia.html The farmboy actor was Max Fairchild, and was also featured in The Road Warrior.

Comment: [Also posted on Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/was-blaster-from-mad-max-beyond-thunderdome-the-same-character-as-the-big-farm)

Comment: I agree. It wouldve been cool to see fifi as Humongous. While fifi was a big guy, the character Humongous seems to have been played by a professional bodybuilder.

Comment: I watched just today (more than 8 years after this question) a sort of documentary about mad max 2 which pointed out that the same extras appear in multiple scenes giving their characters some added depth and this being the same person in both movies would be consistent with that approach. I never thought of this before both reading your question and seeing the video today -- I just assumed that Max took mercy on a mentally-handicapped person. But there is much more to the franchise than meets the eye, that's for sure.

Comment: Dickens used to do stuff like that, at least in David Copperfield.

Answer (score 9):

Having grown up with the Mad Max series, I firmly believe that "Blaster" was indeed the simpleton that lived with "Aunt May" on the farm in the first movie.

That is why Max spared his life when the helmet came off.  He realized who it was.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't seen Thunderdome for ages, but my recollection is that the giant is a congenital idiot, and the smile is just an idiot grin. I don't think any special significance was meant by it.

Answer (score 7):

I never thought about this until I watched Mad Max last night.  I believe it is the same character, not only because they seem to recognize each other in Beyond Thunderdome, but there was some indicative dialogue as well.  Both the Old Lady in Mad Max and Master in Beyond Thunderdome say something to the effect of, "he's only a baby."

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be a few repeated characters in the Mad Max movies *Road Warrior* and *Beyond Thunderdome* only (I don't know of any characters other than Max continue on from the first movie). The pilot played by Bruce Spense is the most notable. Blaster could possibly be the giant that the Biker Gang uses in *Road Warrior*. They are not played by the same actor though and there seems to be no continuation planned between the two. Blaster and the Biker Gang giant who is listed as Humungus in the script are very similar. I always believed that the injury Humungus received caused the brain damage that led to him becoming Blaster, but there seems to be no documented connection.

Comment: *The Road Warrior* was the second "Mad Max" movie, not the original (which was simply called *Mad Max*).  Although I don't recall the large childlike character the OP mentions from *Mad Max*, so I couldn't say for certain you've got the wrong movie.

Comment: The large childlike character from the 1st Mad Max movie lived with the older couple that befriended Maxs family near the end of the film. Indeed, the guy in the third movie was called Blaster. I'm pretty sure Humungus died in Mad Max 2.

Comment: I don't believe there are any characters from Mad Max that are continued into the other movies. I'll edit and clarify that there are three movies. Also I don't believe they show Humungus as dead. I think he's just left for dead.

Comment: Humungus was not shown explicitly as dying but he had such a massive car accident whilst in a very exposed vehicle that it would not be credible if he did not.  It would also break the slightly deeper meaning because as good and evil fight over the future (Wez and Max tugging the feral kid back and forth), good wins and evil destroys itself (Humungus kills Wez(?) and himself in the crash).

Comment: @KevinHowell the title character and the aviator are definitely repeated.

Comment: @Gusdor Actually, no. Bruce Spence plays two different (albeit very similar) characters in the two films - The Gyro-Captain in *Mad Max 2: The Road Warrior* and Jebediah in *Mad Max 3: Beyond Thunderdome".

Answer (score 1):

I agree, it seems likely that the only reason Max would have stopped is the sudden pull back to before the apocalypse back to the moments before the death of his family and it pulled that bit of emotion out. I do recall reading about how Goose was originally going to be the Humungus (the burns he got when he was attacked by Toe Cutter and Humungus obvious burns) but one that always got me was in Thunderdome when Max is Underworld talking to Pig Killer. Was the other slave/guy who looked briefly at Max, Charlie from the first one who gets his thoat cut and looses his voice?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. If you have a new question please use the "Ask Question" button in the upper right to post a question. This space is reserved for answers only.

Answer (score -2):

I have seen all three movies and I firmly believe that not only is
Blaster ("Thunderdome") the large farmhand character
from the first movie, but Humongous could possibly be Fifi, from "Mad 
Max." Why not? After Mad Max ended, we didn't see
the other characters again (except for Max).